# How to display blog category as title in Voltage Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, categories

My client has a site that was built using Themeforest's Voltage Wordpress theme. I have all
of the tweaking they want done except for one thing.

I have created 3 blog categories, with each one being a nav bar item. When I click any of them,
the page that comes has the correct posts on it, but the header on all three pages reads
"Blog Archive".

See here: http://s11.mynewsitereview.com/

The three categories are Fashion & Culture, My Style, and Hints & Tips.

Here is the code from index.php that generates the page title:

```
        <h1><?php
        if(single_cat_title("", false)=='' && !is_archive()) {
            $page = get_page_by_title( single_post_title('', false) );
            $vltg_page_meta=get_post_meta($page->ID, '_vltg_page_meta', true);
            if(isset($vltg_page_meta['display_title']) && $vltg_page_meta['display_title']!='') {
                echo $vltg_page_meta['display_title'];
            } else {
                single_post_title();
            }
        } else if(is_archive()) {

            if ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();

                if(is_day()) {
                    echo get_the_date();
                } else if(is_month()) {
                    echo get_the_date('F Y');
                } else if(is_year()) {
                    echo get_the_date('Y');
                } else {
                    echo 'Blog Archives';
                }

            } else {
                echo 'Blog Archives';
            }

            rewind_posts();

        } else { 
            single_cat_title();
        } ?></h1>
```

I can see *why* it is generating "Blog Archives" as the title, but I don't know how to tweak it
so that it will display the category name instead.

Any help would be most appreciated!

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally solved this one after getting no love from the developer of the Voltage theme.

Have a look at this part of the code I posted in my original question:

```
        } else {
            echo 'Blog Archives';
        }

    } else {
        echo 'Blog Archives';
    }
```

Here is what I changed it to:

```
        } else {
            single_cat_title();
        }

    } else {
        single_cat_title();
    }
```

And it works!